# MAUI VS 2022 17.4.0 - Configure Automatic Provisioning - Certificate Exists But Cannot Be Found in Keychain

Tags: certificate, keychain, maui-blazor

I am brand new to iOS app development.  My app builds and runs on the windows machine and iOS simulator on my Mac Mini.  When I try to run on a connected iPhone, I get the following error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZjgS.png)

I have researched the issue, exported the certificate from my mac keychain as a .p12 file, and installed on my PC build machine, but still no change in error.

Any advice?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, please check what the version of the VS you are using. Go to Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio, if you are `Professional version` please switch to other versions such `Enterprise` or `Community`. Secondly, you don' t need install the `.p12` on your PC. You need to export the certificate from your mac mini to a .p12 file and import the certificate into VS > Tools > options > Xamarin > Apple accounts > View Details > Import certificate and then select the p12 file and import it into VS make sure it display `Valid` on the status column.

Comment: Foolishly, I focused on the Apple Developer Account box and the API Key and thought that the fact that "View Details" was disabled was an error condition rather than a function of the fact that I had not selected a Team name.  Your answer worked perfectly, and I have deployed it to a local device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, please check what the version of the VS you are using. Go to Help->About Microsoft Visual Studio, if you are Professional version please switch to other versions such Enterprise or Community.

Secondly, you don' t need install the .p12 on your PC. You need to export the certificate from your mac mini to a `.p12` file and import the certificate into VS > Tools > options > Xamarin > Apple accounts > View Details > Import certificate and then select the p12 file and import it into VS make sure it display `Valid` on the status column

Answer (score 0):

As I developed yet some Xamarin applications and now had this problem with a new MAUI application, I found a different solution. I tried to but the new app on my local iPhone, but got the error of a not valid old Developer license. This was formerly used.

I tried to import all present certificates from my Mac build machine, but it didn't solve the problem. Some old certificates > 1 year were not importable.
There was no "Apple Development" certificate valid.

As a clicked then on
VS > Tools > options > Xamarin > Apple accounts > View Details > Create certificate
a new "Apple Devlopment: Created via API" was inserted, and this re-enabled me to build for a local iPhone again.